# Prevent server call when collapsing panel

Tags: jquery

I have function called `loadData()`, which is placed in `$(document).ready()`. This calls out to ASP.NET C# `WebMethod`, to populate a `.netDataTables` table using server side processing.

I've added a bootstrap panel to the top of my page, with a clickable region to collapse and show the `.panel-body`. Now, each time I click the icon to toggle the panel body, I'm sending a request to the server by firing off the `loadData()` method.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                Profile
            </div>
            <span class="pull-right clickable" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-stitle="Toggle Summary">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#summary').on('click', '.panel-heading span.clickable', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
            $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
            $this.addClass('panel-collapsed');
            $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
        } else {
            $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
            $this.removeClass('panel-collapsed');
            $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
        }
        oMessageDate.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
    });
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

    LoadData();

});

function LoadData() {
    var sender = "<%= ddBICS.SelectedValue %>";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/LoadData",
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({
            sender: sender
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (xhr) {

            var contentType = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
            if (xhr.status === 401 && contentType.toLowerCase().indexOf("text/html") >= 0) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        },
        success: function (msg) {

        }
    });
}
```

**How can I trigger the toggle without firing off the `loadData()`?**

Comment: Are you sure you're not calling `LoadData` elsewhere? You currently have `LoadData()` outside of the event handler, so that won't get called with your current code.

Comment: LoadData is insdide of document.ready, so gets called everytime the dom has finished loading. I've stripped my code down to only tis scripts, so certain the issue is with the document.ready